# Obtener valor de un select

Tags: javascript

Al tratar de obtener el valor de un select en las variables ffinicial y ffactual como resultado me muestra algo muy diferente.

El código html es el siguiente:

```
<div class="s12"> <!-- Seleccion de fechas -->
    <div class="input-field col s3">
        <!-- Fecha Inicial -->
        <select name="idFInicial" id="idFInicial">
            <?php
            $sql = "select distinct FRegistro from regmedidas order by FRegistro desc; ";
            $query = $conexion->query($sql);
            if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['FRegistro'] . '">' . $row['FRegistro'] . '</option>';
                }
            } else {
                echo "ERROR al realizar la consulta de FRegistro";
            };
            ?>
        </select>
        <label>Fecha Inicial</label>
    </div>
```

Y el script es:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        
        $('#idFFinal').change(function fecha (){
            var ffinicial =  $('#idFInicial').val;
            var ffactual =  $('#idFFinal').val;
            console.log(ffinicial+" "+ffactual);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Este es el resultado que no entiendo muy bien:

```
function(n){var r,e,i,t=this[0];return arguments.length?(i=m(n),this.each(function(e){var t;1===this.nodeType&&(null==(t=i?n.call(this,e,S(this).val()):n)?t="":"number"==typeof t?t+="":Array.isArray(t)&&(t=S.map(t,function(e){return null==e?"":e+""})),(r=S.valHooks[this.type]||S.valHooks[this.nodeName.toLowerCase()])&&"set"in r&&void 0!==r.set(this,t,"value")||(this.value=t))})):t?(r=S.valHooks[t.type]||S.valHooks[t.nodeName.toLowerCase()])&&"get"in r&&void 0!==(e=r.get(t,"value"))?e:"string"==typeof(e=t.value)?e.replace(xt,""):null==e?"":e:void 0} function(n){var r,e,i,t=this[0];return arguments.length?(i=m(n),this.each(function(e){var t;1===this.nodeType&&(null==(t=i?n.call(this,e,S(this).val()):n)?t="":"number"==typeof t?t+="":Array.isArray(t)&&(t=S.map(t,function(e){return null==e?"":e+""})),(r=S.valHooks[this.type]||S.valHooks[this.nodeName.toLowerCase()])&&"set"in r&&void 0!==r.set(this,t,"value")||(this.value=t))})):t?(r=S.valHooks[t.type]||S.valHooks[t.nodeName.toLowerCase()])&&"get"in r&&void 0!==(e=r.get(t,"value"))?e:"string"==typeof(e=t.value)?e.replace(xt,""):null==e?"":e:void 0}
```

Comment: Y por qué no leíste la [documentación de jQuery.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/)? Qué palabras utilizaste en el cuadro de búsqueda de google? Yo puse jquery val y me salió inmediatamente la documentación.

Answer (score 3):

Te falta () después de cada val, $.val es un función en si, lo que te esta asignando en tus variables es la definición de la función, para ejecutarla tienes que terminarla con ()

```
var ffinicial =  $('#idFInicial').val();
var ffactual =  $('#idFFinal').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo recuerda que las funciones para ser ejecutadas deben llevar un () al final, no estas obteniendo los valores por que la funcion .val() no se esta ejecutando, deberias probar de esta manera.

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        
        $('#idFFinal').change(function fecha (){
            var ffinicial =  $('#idFInicial').val();
            var ffactual =  $('#idFFinal').val();
            console.log(ffinicial+" "+ffactual);
        });
    });
</script>
```